# Drop row based on condition

Tags: pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Charlie'],
     'message': ['start', 'stuck', 'finish', 'start', 'stuck', 'start', 'stuck', 'finish', 'finish']}
)
```

and I want to drop all rows with message "stuck" from all rows that don't have a message "finish":

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Charlie', 'Charlie', 'Charlie'],
     'message': ['start', 'finish', 'start', 'stuck', 'start', 'finish', 'finish']}
)
```

So Bill never "finished", so his message will remain "stuck".

Answer (score 1):

To get if any student has finished, group by `student` and use `any`, here we want it back in the original shape of the dataframe so we use `groupby.transform`:

```
>>> sf = df['message'].eq('finish').groupby(df['name']).transform('any')
>>> sf
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: message, dtype: bool
```

From there it’s easy to remove messages that are stuck from students that have not finished yet:

```
>>> df[~sf | df['message'].ne('stuck'))]
      name message
0     Adam   start
2     Adam  finish
3     Bill   start
4     Bill   stuck
5  Charlie   start
7  Charlie  finish
8  Charlie  finish
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will work:**

```
df[~((df.name.isin(df[df.message=="finish"]['name'])) & (df.message=='stuck'))]
```

**Output:**

| name | message |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | start |
| Adam | finish |
| Bill | start |
| Bill | stuck |
| Charlie | start |
| Charlie | finish |
| Charlie | finish |